# Pygame rotate line delete old line

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

How can I rotate a line in **pygame** using `math` module and every second rotate line delete old line. I've just used other code but the problem was old line rotate and so I watched an sunshine effect.

Comment: If you have code that's not working as expected, you should post it

Comment: You probably need to refresh you background and then redraw your rotated line. Typically that's done by calling surface.fill(_some colour_) before drawing your line every frame.

Comment: I used Math method with sin e cos. Of you search in stackowerflow "pygame rotate line" you found my because i copied it. Big the problem was old line Eric where put surface.fill command in script ?? And in tis mod i modify all display ???

Comment: Please add your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question and try to explain more thoroughly what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42316493/7675174) to the line rotation question, it shows where to use the `surface.fill(..)` function.

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared a generic example that randomises one end point of a line when a mouse button is clicked.

```
# pyg_line_demo
import pygame
import random

def get_random_position():
    """return a random (x,y) position in the screen"""
    return (random.randint(0, screen_width - 1),  #randint includes both endpoints.
            random.randint(0, screen_height - 1)) 

def random_line(line):
    """ Randomise an end point of the line"""
    if random.randint(0,1):
        return [line[0], get_random_position()]
    else:
        return [get_random_position(), line[-1]]
        

# initialisation
pygame.init()
screen_width, screen_height = 640, 480
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Lines')
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
FPS = 30

# initial line
line = [(10, 10), (200, 200)]

finished = False
while not finished:
    for event in pygame.event.get():            
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            line = random_line(line)
    #redraw background
    surface.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
    #draw line
    pygame.draw.aalines(surface, pygame.Color("blue"), False, line)
    # update display
    pygame.display.update()
    #limit framerate
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

You should be able to insert your line rotation function in place of the `random_line()` function.

[image: Random lines example]