# How can I draw an object dependent on the state of a variable in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a dungeon game and I've added a flashlight in it, now I want the flashlight to disappear when the player collides with it, here is the part with flashlight and the player:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init

flashlight = 1
if flashlight ==1:
    flashlight = pygame.draw.rect(win, RED, (item_spawns_x,item_spawns_y, 32, 32))

Player = pygame.draw.rect(win, WHITE, (x, y, 32, 32))
if Player.colliderect(flashlight):
    flashlight = 0

if flashlight == 0:
    del flashlight
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53036295/11639518) help? I see it references a technique for filling the screen by redrawing the background. ```surface.fill``` in the answer's example.

Comment: Perhaps the question title can be modified, then? It seems to not be doing the question justice. @Rabbid76

Comment: @Rabbid76 The question here is, "How do I delete a rect in pygame?". The question in the post I recommended this is duplicates is, "How to delete rects/sprites with python and pygame"? In both cases, the question title would indicate that we're trying to delete rects in pygame -- and in the answer provided the earlier question, indeed references how to delete a rect. So if the flashlight in this question isn't a rect, it seems one of the questions is misleading, and its title ought to be modified.

Comment: @jhelphenstine Oh, I see your point. In this case the user tries  to draw an object, dependent on the state of a variable. So I suggest you change the title of the question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 easily done; thanks for showing me the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. `flashlight` is a state, which indicates if the flashlight is on, so you should not assign the return value of `pygame.draw.rect()` to `flashlight`. You've to use a separate variable for the flashlight rectangle (e.g. `flash_rect`).
You've to implement a game loop, which continuously redraws the scene. When the flashlight has to be switched off, then you've to change the state of the variable `flashlight`. e.g.:

```py
flashlight = 1

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)

    if flashlight == 1:
        flash_rect = pygame.draw.rect(win, RED, (item_spawns_x,item_spawns_y, 32, 32))   
    player_rect = pygame.draw.rect(win, WHITE, (x, y, 32, 32))

    if flashlight and player_rect.colliderect(flash_rect):
        flashlight = 0

    pygame.display.update()
```